# How can I setup ubuntu to use my mixer/audio interface?

Tags: command-line, drivers, sound, pulseaudio, jack

I'm new to linux so I don't really know how to use my external audio interface (Zoom L-8 Mixer) thru usb, the only output/input option on my settings is my internal audio card.
I would really appreciate an in depth instructions on how to set it up.
I don't really know anything about linux and just decided to install it, because f*** windows and I know it'll be worth the learning curve.

Comment: https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=19580 <- Here people are saying everything just works. You're probably missing something as it should show up as an input device in the scrolldown menu. But please take a time to [edit] the question and add your Ubuntu release/flavor and show your sound settings. Also remove any unnecessary text, keep it "professional", and use proper capitalization, sentences, etc.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank u very much for the reply, the forum u sent helped me a lot, I just did the mod and turned on IOS mode on my mixer, and it worked like a charm.